# How to cal tcl commands inside my python script using tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pytest, performance-testing

I am running my performance test on python and *I want to call some Tcl commands using Tkinter inside my python script.*

Can somebody please help me to write the code,

```py
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()

root.tk.eval('puts {printed by tcl}')
```

I tried simply above example, here when I do `root=tkinter.tk()` it opens up a window, I just want to execute my command and get the result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Python functions in Tkinter.Tcl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701909/using-python-functions-in-tkinter-tcl)

Comment: Your code works for me. The tcl code is executed and the message is printed.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have tried will not show any window until you put the `root.mainloop()`,but you can try something like this,

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

root.tk.eval('puts {printed by tcl}')

root.destroy()
root.mainloop()
```

here `withdraw()` will remove the window from the screen without destroying it and then you can perform your tasks and then destroy it at the end of code.

Comment: In my actual code, I have to run a command call "vsi", when I run the command vsi using tclscript, vsi gets executed,Here I get error 
from tkinter import Tcl

tcl= Tcl()
tcl.eval('puts {printed by tcl}')
tcl.eval('vsi')
Error :printed by tcl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tkex.py", line 5, in <module>
    tcl.eval('vsi')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "vsi"
 I am seeing above error